# How to continue playing MediaPlayer from changin activities in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have an Activity-A play video then i i click button ill pass the getcurrenttime to Activity-B to continue my video.

My question is, what is the proper way to do this involving each activity life cycle from activity A-B the onpause, onstart, onresume, what is the proper way?

Comment: You want to continue playing the video on the other activity ? means continue from the whole buffer ?

Comment: yup but i dont know where to put the right codes in the states, example activity-a i get the mp.getCurrentPosition() where should i put it the best way from onPause() and if i want to use the value to activityB using mp.seekto(fromA), where should i put it onRestoreinstantState?